# Asignar valor en div con Class

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un pequeño problema.

Quiero asignar un valor a un `div` con diferentes clases, necesito cambiar el de arriba por el de abajo

```
<div class="product-container text-center product-block" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Product">

<div class="product-container text-center product-block" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
```

Estoy probando primero a añadir un `ID` y si funciona añadir después la información necesaria, pero no logro hacerlo. Aquí mi código `JS`

```
function myFunction() {
 var guru = document.getElementsByClassName('product-container text-center product-block');
 var guru = document.setAttribute("id", "democlass"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

el método `getElementsByClassName` lo que retorna es un elemento de tipo Nodelist, lo que pasa aquí es que selecciona todos los elementos con la clase que hallas colocado en este caso `getElementsByClassName('product-container text-center product-block')`, lo que pasa aquí es que selecciona todos los elemento con esas dos clases y la forma para acceder a ellos es diferente a la de un`getElementById` ya que hay que considerar que puedes tener mas de un elemento con la misma clase, asi que para acceder a algún elemento es atraves de un array, no usando la variables sola sino como un array con la posición del elemento, para dejarlo mas en claro aquí esta el ejemplo en código.

```
guru[0].setAttribute("id", "democlass");
```

no

```
var guru = document.setAttribute("id", "democlass");
```

y si hay mas de un elemento se utilizan sus otras posiciones pertinentes como 1,2,3,4,etc.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo tu código estas declarando dos veces la misma variable, lo que tienes que hacer es primero obtener tu elemento y guardardo en una variable, puedes utilizar `document.getElementsByClassName` lo cual te regresa un arreglo con todos los elementos que tienen esas clases. Si solo buscas un elemento, te recomiendo utilizar `document.getElementById` el cual solo te va a regresar el elemento que tenga ese Id.

Ya que tienes tu elemento guardado en una variable, podrás utilizar la función `setAttribute` como lo estas haciendo.

Un ejemplo para tu código quedaría así:

Tu elemento con las clases `product-container text-center product-block`:

```
<div class="product-container text-center product-block" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Product">
```

La funcion que busca el elemento y le modifica el atributo `itemtype`:

```
function myFunction() {
 var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('product-container text-center product-block');
 elem[0].setAttribute("itemtype", "https://schema.org/ListItem"); 
}
```

Presta atención en el uso de `[0]` lo que hace esto es obtener el primer elemento del arreglo retornado por `documento.getElementsByClassName` si quisieras modificar todos los elementos, lo tendrás que hacer con cada elemento dentro del arreglo.

Answer (score 0):

```js
elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('miClass'); // este buscara todos los elementos con esa clase y no solo uno
/**
 * Puedes asignar un id al primer elemento de esta forma
 **/
elementos[0].setAttribute('id', 'miId');
console.log(elementos);
```

```html
<div class="miClass">
<div class="miClass"> 
<div class="miClass">
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar también `document.querySelectorAll` que de igual forma te trae un array de los elementos HTML que coincidan con el nombre, clase, etc., y accedes a ellos por medio del índice:

```js
     var guru = document.querySelectorAll('.product-container.text-center.product-block');
    console.log(guru[0]);
console.log(guru[1]);

guru[0].setAttribute('itemtype','https://schema.org/ListItem');
```

```html
<div class="product-container text-center product-block" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Product">

<div class="product-container text-center product-block" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
```